# How would one use `\titlesec` to make drop-caps sections?

Tags: titlesec

I am unsure of if `\titlesec` can do this, but I would like to use it to replace using `\lettrine` + `\addtocontents` for the same thing.

What I want should look like this:

[image: An image]

There is no problem with using `\lettrine`, it is just a lot more manual code than I would like, if it is just for the same, repeated style.
I suppose I could always make a macro, but still.

Edit: I thought it was clear, but to clarify, You have the number 1, which is a chapter number.
Currently, this looks like:

```
            \lettrine[lines=2,nindent=0pt,findent=2pt]{\textbf{1}}{}%
            %
            In the beginning God creäted the heaven and the earth.
            %
            $^{2}$And the earth was without form, and void;
                %
                and darkness \textit{was} upon the face of the deep.
            %
            And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.
```

What I should like to do, however, is replace `\lettrine[lines=2,nindent=0pt,findent=2pt]{\textbf{1}}{}%` with `\section{}`.

In the titlesec documentatio, one of the examples of titles is:

```
\titleformat{\section}[wrap]
        {\normalfont\fontseries{b}\selectfont\filright}
        {\thesection.}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
        {12pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}
```

This modifies the `\section{}` so that it wraps text around the section and places an empty line at the bottom.
I should like to do something similar to what I have done with `\lettrine` though I am unsure of how to do that.

Comment: *The First Day* is part of the section title?

Comment: Actually, what I did there is used a subsection before where I want to use a section.  It is a weird way to do it, yes.

Comment: Could you post a minimal code of what you've tried and clearly what  you'd like to achieve.

Comment: Added a bit more.

Comment: I wouldn't use `\section` to begin with, but define my own command.

Comment: @egreg That is what I am leaning toward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xparse}

\titleformat{\section}[wrap]
        {\normalfont\fontseries{b}\selectfont\filright}
        {}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
        {12pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}

\NewDocumentCommand\mysection{ O{#2} m }{%
  \section[#1]{#2}
  \everypar\expandafter{%
    \the\everypar
    \lettrine[lines=2,nindent=0pt,findent=2pt]{\textbf{\thesection}}{}}
}

\begin{document}
\mysection{Title}

In the beginning God creäted the heaven and the earth.
$^{2}$And the earth was without form, and void;
    and darkness \textit{was} upon the face of the deep.
And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.

In the beginning God creäted the heaven and the earth.
$^{2}$And the earth was without form, and void;
    and darkness \textit{was} upon the face of the deep.
And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**: With paragraph hooks introduced in LaTeX2e Jun 2021, this can be achieved more robust (less chance to be incompatible with other packages/settings). You may want to set smaller after-sep for `\section`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{xparse} % since latex2e Oct 2020, xparse is part of the kernel

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
        {\normalfont\fontseries{b}\selectfont\raggedright}
        {}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
        {12pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}

\NewDocumentCommand\mysection{ O{#2} m }{%
  \section[#1]{#2}
  % need latex2e Jun 2021
  \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{%
    \lettrine[lines=2,nindent=0pt,findent=2pt]{\textbf{\thesection}}{}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\mysection{Title}

In the beginning God creäted the heaven and the earth.
$^{2}$And the earth was without form, and void;
    and darkness \textit{was} upon the face of the deep.
And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.

In the beginning God creäted the heaven and the earth.
$^{2}$And the earth was without form, and void;
    and darkness \textit{was} upon the face of the deep.
And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! (sorry it took so long to return an answer).  This was above and beyond what I expected.  I do want to note one thing, when I went to actually test this, for `\NewDocumentCommand\mysection{ O{#2} m }{%`, I misread it as `\NewDocumentCommand\mysection{ ZERO{#2} m }{%`.

Comment: @MatþewScarbrough I've added a new and better approach which makes use of newly introduced paragraph hooks. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out when I get a chance.